# Laravel yield doesn't show the contents

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, yield

Yield functions doesn't load particular sections in other files.

**Route**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('add-listing');
});
```

**add-listing.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')

@section('body')
  This is add-listing page
@stop
```

**header.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')

@section('header')
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Find Do Responsive Directory Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/color-green.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/short_icon.png">
@stop
```

**layout.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @yield('header')
</head>
<body>

    @yield('body')

</body>
```

When I run this only the `@section('body')` content is loading. It doesn't load the `@section('header')`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `@include('header')` in layout :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @include('header')
</head>
<body>

    @yield('body')

</body>
```

**header.blade.php** :

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Find Do Responsive Directory Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/color-green.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/short_icon.png">
```

Comment: Why can't I use `@yield('header')`?

Comment: yield works only if your view extends the parent view. It loads code from a section in the view blade which extends the layout. You are loading only add-listing view that extends layout blade. On the other hand @include, similar to include(), imports the file.

Answer (score 0):

In this example you call add-listing.blade.php and in this file just you said call layout.blade so your blades don't call header.blade just prepare a section for get header contents and you don't call header.blade in your flow.

Yield is such as a variable that can be set by section:

@yield('header') ~ echo $header

@section('header')

header value is here

@endsection

So $header = header value is here.